# Is President Obama's disuse of the subjunctive defensible?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

In today's NYTimes op-ed, no lesser an authority on English language usage than President Obama [says](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/08/opinion/president-barack-obama-guns-are-our-shared-responsibility.html):

> They include making sure that anybody engaged in the business of
>   selling firearms conducts background checks [..].

My ear tells me that the subjunctive mood should be used:

> They include making sure that anybody engaged in the business of
>   selling firearms conduct background checks [..].

Should it be used? May it be used? Must it be used? I'm asking this way because it's clear the subjunctive is disappearing from English, but I didn't think we were so far along its disappearance for the sentence above to stand (from Obama) without it.

*Don't get me wrong*. Past American presidents have nucular-bombed our ears with incorrect pronunciation and mediocre grammar, but I don't recall ever hearing either candidate or President Obama misuse a word or disuse an English rule. Indeed, he seems to be able to memorize important sentences with [split infinitive](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/01/22/opinion/22pinker.html) even when it's easily avoided.

Comment: *Make sure* and *ensure* don't in my experience ordinarily take the subjunctive: "Make sure that your son eats his vegetables."

Comment: That subjunctive sounds utterly wrong to my American ear. You might be able to get away with using it with *ensure*, but not *make sure*. And [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ensure+that+he+is%2C+ensure+that+he+be%2C+make+sure+that+he+is%2C+make+sure+that+he+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Censure%20that%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Censure%20that%20he%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20sure%20that%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0) is an Ngram that agrees with me.

Comment: These days it's the use of the so-called "subjunctive" that needs to be defended!

Comment: @PeterShor Very interesting. Yet another little jewel that Google doesn't bother publicizing. Indeed "{make sure|ensure} that he be" sound wrong to my ear as well. I guess in English consulting past books is as good a litmus test as it can get.

Comment: No problem with indicative, but **is conducting** would be better.

Comment: Why does this seem more like a tirade against Obama rather than a question about English?

Comment: Indefensible! Other than that the subjunctive in English is barely there anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Er... President Obama has it right (!).

We must ...'make sure that anybody engaged in the business of selling firearms does, indeed, conduct background checks'.

He is exhorting us to ensure that something does happen.  Like when you ask the baby-sitter to make sure little Johnny goes to bed at 7pm.  There is no ambiguity, hypothesising, or ordering involved.  On the contrary Obama is expressing clearly and objectively what will be done (to the best of his ability).

Answer (score 1):

Obama is using the language to underscore his opinion about how important it is that these checks happen.  It is defensible.   **He is most certainly not providing the "death knell" of the subjunctive**.

Elsewhere in his [recent speech on gun control](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/01/05/president-obamas-amazingly-emotional-speech-on-gun-control-annotated/), particularly the part talking about [funding for research](http://www.onthemedia.org/story/why-cdc-cant-research-gun-violence/), highlights his use of subjunctive to help make a point, e.g.: "With more research, we ***could*** further improve gun safety, just as with more research we've reduced traffic fatalities enormously over the last 30 years."

Finally, a US president should not necessarily be considered an authority on the English Language the way the Queen of England might be.  Do obvious examples of why need to be made explicit?

Comment: The "death knell" was tangential to my question. I removed that term. (I'm a fan of the subjunctive mood myself!)

Comment: Please do not misunderestimate the need for explicitness. =D

Comment: @BrianDonovan +1, but you picked such a [subtle](http://www.tafinn.com/andyfinn-us/bush_league/bushisms_mispronunciation.htm) example there; I'm afraid many won't *explicitly* catch the reference! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The American present tense subjunctive follows after verbs of demand.
As "to make sure + that-clause is no verb of demand there is no reason for a subjunctive.